# Missing feature

Tags: package

Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: Lightning Community Themes.

But I have already added the theme in the package.

Please provide a suggestion in this regard.

Comment: Please be more specific. Which package? What permissions have been configured for it?

Answer (score 2):

Missing feature error while installing package occurs due to two following causes:

1. Org does not support the feature like for instance Professional edition.
2. Package has a dependency of complaining feature.

If you are not on PE org, try [`Enabling communities`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable.htm&type=5) on the destination org before installing the package.

Comment: Thanks after Enabling community it is working fine.